# Alinhamento de imagem com CSS

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma `div` que contem outra `div` dentro, porém esta segunda `div` (de dentro) contem um `<img src="">`, como eu posso fazer para deixar esta `div` com a imagem alinhada no centro da primeira `div`? já tentei `vertical-align`, `horizontal-align` e etc e nada da certo.

[Aqui está no exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/vwb19mhh/3/)

```css
#clientes-logo1
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white; 
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    display:inline-block;
}

#logotipo-clientes 
{
    width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    /* vertical-align: middle; -- não funciona */
    /* horizontal-align: middle; -- não funciona */
    margin: 50px 5px 0px 15px; /* se usar assim a div principal desalinha */
}
```

```html
<div id="clientes">
  <h1>Clientes</h1>
  <div id="clientes-logo1">
    <img id="logotipo-clientes" src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" title="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alinhar na vertical:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clientes">
  <h1>Clientes</h1>

  <div class="clientes-logo">
    <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" title="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="clientes-logo">
    <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" title="" alt="" width="100">
  </div>

  <div class="clientes-logo">
    <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" title="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#clientes {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.clientes-logo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white; 
    display:inline-block;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

.clientes-logo img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
```

Lembre-se que ao repetir um elemento que herdará os mesmos estilos, use **class** e não **id**.

Comment: Alinhou na vertical mas não na horizontal, eu poderia até usar `margin-top: 20%;` só que se uma imagem for maior que a outra eles não ficaram exatamente no centro da div principal.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, como assim? Com o que te passei ele alinha horizontalmente e não verticalmente. Assim mesmo, você quer alinhar nos dois sentidos. Mas em relação a que? Sua div clientes tem heigth auto.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, tente agora.

Comment: minha div de `logotipo-clientes` esta dentro da div `clientes-logo1`, a div `clientes-logo1`possui 250 por 200px, e a div da imagem possui 220 em width e `auto em height para não distorcer` eu gostaria que a imagem de dentro (logotipo-clientes) ficasse no meio da div `clientes-logo1`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, define um height para clientes-logo1 e usa a alteração que fiz. Deve funcionar.

Comment: aparentente funcionou só que se eu usar display: inline-block eles não ficam um do lado do outro, e eu não quero que a div principal se adeque ao tamanho da imagem, eu quero que o tamanho seja fixo e que a imagem de dentro fique no meio dela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26890/discussion-between-rafael-acioly-and-buback).

Comment: Adiciona um left: 50% e também um translate pro X - algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/L1e8rymm/

Comment: @Ricardo, boa observação. Vou adicionar.

Answer (score 3):

Em uma busca com esse mesmo problema um dia encontrei essa solução!

///////// CSS

```
.center
    {
        display:         flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

//////// HTML

```
<div class="center">
            <img id="logotipo-clientes" src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" title="" alt="">
</div>
```